# Why return doesn’t break the loop and function?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I'm new to javascript and trying to build a triangle. Here is a piece of code.

```
function makeLine (length){
    var line = "";
    for (x = 1; x <= length; x++){
        line += "* ";
    }
    return line + "\n";
}

function buildTriangle (length){
var x = ""
    for (j = 1; j <= length; j++){
        x += makeLine(j);
    }
    return x
｝

console.log(buildTriangle(10))
```

It seems that return would break the loop and function.

Then why return doesn't break the function and continue to loop?

And why the result is completely different if i slightly change the second function to

```
function buildTriangle (length){
var x = ""
    for (j = 1; j <= length; j++){
        x = makeLine(j);
    }
    return x
｝
```

Comment: Your returns are not inside the loops.

Comment: Your loop condition isn't logical (>= ?)

Comment: sorry it should be <=

Comment: Also in tour buildTriangle function you have “j>=length” but you’re supplying a length of 10 and initiating j as 1 so it’ll never run.

Comment: `Then why return doesn't break the function and continue to loop?` for which `return` do you expect that it  behave differently and why/how?

Comment: just edited, should be j<=length

Comment: Does it mean that only when the return is inside the for loop, it would exit the function immediately?

Comment: `return` exits the function in which it is immediately. And that happens in your code. Why do you think that this is not the case?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between your first function and 2nd, that in the first you used "+=" which adds the makeLine function to what allready in "x". In your 2nd function you used just "=" so you declare x to be  that makeLine function, which in other words means that your overriding it.

Answer (score -1):

The return statement will not break the loop because it's outside of the for statement's scope. It is set to return a string after the loop.

I think what's wrong with your code is the declaration of your for method on the BuildTriangle function. Take a look at it:

```
for (j = 1; j >= length; j++){
    x += makeLine(j);
}
```

The way its written it will call the makeLine function when j is more than or equal to length. Since j starts as 1, it will never call the makeLine function. You can fix by inverting the sign, like this:

```
for (j = 1; j <= length; j++){
    x += makeLine(j);
}
```